# Looping through a method without for/foreach/while

Tags: c#, for-loop

Is there a way of calling a method/lines of code multiple times not using a for/foreach/while loop?

For example, if I were to use to for loop:

```
int numberOfIterations = 6;
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; i++)
{
   DoSomething();
   SomeProperty = true;
}
```

The lines of code I'm calling don't use 'i' and in my opinion the whole loop declaration hides what I'm trying to do. This is the same for a foreach.

I was wondering if there's a looping statement I can use that looks something like:

```
do(6)
{
   DoSomething();
   SomeProperty = true;
}
```

It's really clear that I just want to execute that code 6 times and there's no noise involving index instantiating and adding 1 to some arbitrary variable.

As a learning exercise I have written a static class and method:

```
Do.Multiple(int iterations, Action action)
```

Which works but scores very highly on the pretentious scale and I'm sure my peers wouldn't approve.

I'm probably just being picky and a for loop is certainly the most recognisable, but as a learning point I was just wondering if there (cleaner) alternatives. Thanks.

(I've had a look at this thread, but it's not *quite* the same)
[Using IEnumerable without foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248985/using-ienumerable-without-foreach-loop)

Comment: stick with a for loop. That way everyone knows what it is.

Comment: Hmmm, you want to execute the same code 6 times ?  Are you just trying to waste time, or does the executed code have side-effects ?  In either case, shame on you.

Comment: I honestly fail to see what isn't clean about a for loop.

Comment: Easy there @Mark, take a look at your old code lately?

Comment: How do you know how many iterations have been completed with out a counter?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I was just wondering if it was possible, not whether it was a good idea.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - Love the comment! Others need to find a sense of humor.  Especially on a question like this!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, the `for` loop does not hide what you're trying to do.
Anyone reading your code is already familiar with standard `for` loops and will understand instantly what you're doing.

Comment: I agree 100% but I would get rid of `numberOfIterations` because it doesn't really make it any clearer.

Comment: I only used that as part of the fake example in the question. But valid point

Answer (score 10):

You could score even more highly on the pretension scale by making it an extension method:

```
public static void Times(this int iterations, Action action)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        action();
    }
}
...
6.Times(() => {
    DoSomething();
    SomeProperty = true;
});
```

But I would definitely stick with a `for` loop. It's the idiomatic, well-recognised way of doing it.

Comment: Love it... have to find an excuse to use that sometime :)

Comment: Really nice. It's almost tempting :p

Comment: This is absolutely the way to go.  We have made it a standard on my team.

Answer (score 2):

Not a loop in sight

```
private MethodDelegate MultiMethod(MethodDelegate m, int count) {
  MethodDelegate a;
  if (count > 0) {
    a = m;
    a += MultiMethod(m, --count);
  } else {
    a = delegate { };
  }
  return a;
}
```

and you get a great syntax for invocation!

```
MultiMethod(action, 99)();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a do....until or if...then

Use a counter inside the loop and have it loop UNTIL the counter reaches 6.

Or an if-then statement with a counter. If your value is 6, break out of the loop.

I'm not a programming guru, but if you have an action that needs to be done a set number of times, there would be a need for a counter somewhere, whether it's a function of your loop or if it has to be created with a counter.