# consuming sequence generated by IEnumerable

Tags: c#, yield-return

I would like to use an `IEnumerable` to generate a sequence of values -- specifically, a list of Excel-like column headers.

```
private IEnumerable<string> EnumerateSymbolNames()
{
  foreach (var sym in _symbols)
  {
    yield return sym;
  }

  foreach (var sym1 in _symbols)
  {
    foreach (var sym2 in _symbols)
    {
      yield return sym1 + sym2;
    }
  }

  yield break;
}
private readonly string[] _symbols = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", ...};
```

This works fine if I fetch the values from a `foreach` loop.  But what I want is to use the iterator block as a state machine and fetch the next available column header in response to a user action.  And this -- consuming the generated values -- is where I've run into trouble.

So far I've tried

```
return EnumerateSymbolNames().Take(1).FirstOrDefault();

return EnumerateSymbolNames().Take(1).SingleOrDefault();

return EnumerateSymbolNames().FirstOrDefault();

var enumerator = EnumerateSymbolNames().GetEnumerator();
enumerator.MoveNext();
return enumerator.Current;
```

... but none of these have worked.  (All repeatedly return "A".)
Based on the responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248985/using-ienumerable-without-foreach-loop), I'm wondering what I want is even possible -- although several of the responses to that post suggest techniques similar to my last one.

And no, this is *not* a homework assignment :)

Comment: In your last example, just make `enumerator` a field and initialize it once instead of calling `EnumerateSymbolNames().GetEnumerator()` everytime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `GetEnumerator`, you need to use the same enumerator for each iteration.  If you call GetEnumerator a second time, it will start over at the beginning of the collection.

If you want to use `Take`, you must first `Skip` the number of records that have already been processed.

Comment: Not to contradict anything in this answer, but to add, the *enumerator* is the state machine mentioned in the question. The *enumerable* produces a new instance of that state machine, in the initial state.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me...

```
var states = EnumerateSymbolNames();
var stateMachine = states.GetEnumerator();

do
{
  //something
} while (stateMachine.MoveNext());
```

When print the results within that loop, it successfully produced the following output:

```
A
B
C
...
AA
AB
AC
...
BA
BB
...
```

Which is what I think you intended...

Answer (score 0):

As both @cadrell0's answer and @Mr Steak's comment point out, what I needed to do was retain a reference to the enumerator returned by `EnumerateSymbolNames().GetEnumerator()`.

When you're in a `foreach` loop, this is done implicitly for you: the iterator variable wraps an enumerator, which (I'm assuming) is scoped locally to the loop.  So -- and this is the key piece -- when the iterator block does (the equivalent of)

```
enumerator.MoveNext();
return enumerator.Current;
```

... you're always using the *same* enumerator.  Whereas what I was doing was creating / obtaining a *different* (new) enumerator every time.  And predictably, it always started out at the first position in the sequence.  This was probably obvious to everyone but me; it seems obvious to me as well in hindsight.  (I was thinking of the enumerator as sort of a singleton property of the sequence, assuming that I'd be getting the same enumerator back every time.)

The following does what I want:

```
public class SymbolGenerator
{
    private readonly string[] _symbols = { "A", "B", "C", ... };

    private readonly IEnumerator<string> _enumerator;

    public SymbolGenerator()
    {
        _enumerator = EnumerateSymbols().GetEnumerator();
    }

    public string GetNextSymbol()
    {
        _enumerator.MoveNext();
        return _enumerator.Current;
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> EnumerateSymbols()
    {
        // (unchanged)
    }
}
```