# How do I move a loop forward "in place"?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to "seek" through an loop?  Based on certain conditions, I want to do a "continue in place," to fast forward through a loop.  Like this:

```
for(var thing in things)
{
  // Do stuff

  if(something)
  {
     // Move iteration forward until the iteration object ("thing") meets the right condition
     while(true)
     { 
       // Move the iteration forward...somehow
       [Missing code goes here]
       if(thing.Property == somevalue)
       {
         break;
       }
     }
  }

  // Do more stuff on the new value of "thing"
}
```

I could use `continue`, but *I don't want to go back to the top of the loop*.  I want to cycle forward through the objects in the enumerator, then just pick up where I left off.

I'm guessing this is not possible.  If not, what would be the best logic to emulate what I want to do.

Comment: Cannot you filter the `things` collection before iteration?

Comment: If you can use a `for` loop instead, it's easy (and dangerous) to adjust the loop counter at any point in the loop.  If you have an `IEnumerator`, just call `MoveNext()` until your condition is hit.

Comment: what is the datatype of the `things` object.. if it's a datatable or dataset you could just use the `.Select` method to filter what you need then you will have no need to do all the forward seeking

Comment: Looks like a LINQ/Lamdba expression is need to filter your collection - which would make your code a lot cleaner

Comment: Gosh I hate to see `while(true)` in code

Comment: @DanAndrews how would you insert a unique random value into a database otherwise?

Comment: @zerkms with a [flux capacitor](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Flux_capacitor), of course.   I'm not sure how your comment it relevant to this question.

Comment: @DanAndrews it's relevant to "Gosh I hate to see while(true) in code". How would you do that without `while(true)`?

Comment: @zerkms Sorry dude, I'm still in the context of this question.  Maybe you have another question to propose to the community?

Comment: @DanAndrews okay, I see that your "hate" is irrational. I thought it could be useful for the community to reveal why `while(true)` is bad, now I see that it actually is not. Thanks.

Comment: @zerkms wow.. just wow.  I was trying to not do what we're doing... having an extended discussion in comments.  I hate to see `while(true)` in code because almost every time there is a more readable way to write the code.  Does that mean it's not functional when people do that?  No, it's very functional to `while(true)` and `break`.  Just looks like crap code to me.  You feel differently... I'm okay with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using a standard `for` loop instead of the `foreach` loop you are using?

E.g.

```
var thing;
for (int i = 0; i < things.Length; i++)
{
    thing = things[i];
    //do stuff
    if(something)
    {
        while([thing doesn't meet condition] && i < things.Length - 1 )
        {
            thing = things[++i];
        }
    }
}
```

If you've seen the incrementer before (`i++`), `++i` might seem strange. All it does is increment `i` **before** you use it. So, if you entered the `while` loop on `things[5]`, `thing` would be set to `things[6]`. The `while` loop will also break if you cannot load any more objects.

Comment: Unlike most answers that start with "I can't comment [so I'll answer]", this one is actually a decent answer! I cleaned it up a bit for you. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes, this is a good answer.  I ended up doing a linked list, where every `thing` had a reference to the next `thing`, so I wasn't iterating at all but was rather jumping around an unordered bucket of `things`..  But this is essentially the same thing -- a `for` loop is like a linked list, in the sense that there's an implicit link to the next incremental numeric index.

Comment: @TimS. Thanks! I always forget that you can inline code as well.

Answer (score 2):

Filter things before the loop

```
var filtered = things.Where(x => x.Property == somevalue);
foreach ( var thing in filtered )
{
   if (something)
       // Do more stuff on the new value of "thing"
}
```

Comment: This is going to run the code in a very different order.  If these operations can be reordered without it affecting them, then this is fine, but if these operations cannot be reordered in this way, then this isn't a valid transformation.

Answer (score 0):

you can manually iterate through the iterator

you can take a look here:

[Using IEnumerable without foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248985/using-ienumerable-without-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0):

You can "rebuild" the logic of the `foreach`. Note the `using` (because the `foreach` disposes the enumerator)

```
using (var enu = things.GetEnumerator())
{
    bool success;

    while (success = enu.MoveNext())
    {
        // Current value (always "valid"): enu.Current;

        if (something)
        {
            while (success = enu.MoveNext())
            {
                // Current value (always "valid"): enu.Current;

                if (enu.Current == someValue)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Current value (check success before using it): enu.Current;
        if (success)
        {
            // Do more stuff on the new value of "thing"
        }
    }
}
```

The `if (res)` is necessary because the inner `while` could "exhaust" the enumerator.