# Alternative to foreach in C# Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, razor-2

I need to output complex HTML containing an IEnumerable in a Razor page in an ASP.NET MVC 5 site.

I would like to use nested for loops to structure the HTML - however, this is not possible if all object output is enclosed in a foreach loop.

Rather than use a `foreach` loop, is there any way to do something like this which would get the next object in the sequence:

```
if (x = 1)
{
    for (var x=0; x<2; x++)
    {
        <div class="row">
            for (var n=0; n<4; n++)
            {
                <div class="a">
                    Model.GetNextObject.Name
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    }
}
else
{
    <div class="b">
        Model.GetNextObject.Name
    </div>
}
```

In many situations, this would allow for far more elegant code.

Is this possible?

Comment: Its a bit unclear from your code what your expecting the output from this to be. Can you give a simple example of the values and the expected output

Comment: "In many situations, this would allow for far more elegant code." -- Why would it be so? What do you need a `for` loop for?

Comment: @duplode Say I want complex HTML structure - and need to use if conditions (eg rows & spans/columns in bootstrap) - you need lots of @: to stop errors coming up in Razor.

Comment: @StephenMuecke The output could just be a list of names - the key is being able to get the next object when I want - not tied to the foreach loop - thus enabling more sophisticated structure - multiple nested loops instead of if statements which then require @: to mitigate unclosed html tag errors in Razor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, it is possible,

1. Get the reference to Enumerator using GetEnumerator
2. Call movenext method to move to next element

Refer this stack overflow post
[Using IEnumerable with for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248985/using-ienumerable-without-foreach-loop)

```
var enumerator = getInt().GetEnumerator();
while(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    var MyObject = enumerator.Current;
    Console.WriteLine(MyObject.Property);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! To improve the answer for future users any chance of a code sample pasted in here?

Comment: The link I referred here contains the sample code, I don't want to copy and paste the code, so i refered the code. may be in future i will start paste sample code.

Comment: Thanks - stack overflow just like the code to be in the answer - rather than using an external reference - I guess for convenience - and in case that link goes dead at some point in future. I've pasted here - thx.

Comment: The Enumerator is outputting the text "True" to the page when there is a enumerator.MoveNext() statement without the if. Do you know how to stop that? (I could insert an empty if but it's not very elegant). thx.