# Recursive generator without explicit enumerators

Tags: c#, generator, yield-return, ienumerator

Here is a generator which uses explicit enumerators:

```
static IEnumerable<string> generate(string s)
{
    yield return new Regex("e").Replace(s, "", 1);

    yield return new Regex("aaaa").Replace(s, "e", 1);
    yield return new Regex("aa").Replace(s, "bb", 1);
    yield return new Regex("ba").Replace(s, "abbb", 1);

    yield return new Regex("bb").Replace(s, "aa", 1);

    var en0 = generate(new Regex("e").Replace(s, "", 1)).GetEnumerator();
    var en1 = generate(new Regex("aaaa").Replace(s, "e", 1)).GetEnumerator();
    var en2 = generate(new Regex("aa").Replace(s, "bb", 1)).GetEnumerator();
    var en3 = generate(new Regex("ba").Replace(s, "abbb", 1)).GetEnumerator();
    var en4 = generate(new Regex("bb").Replace(s, "aa", 1)).GetEnumerator();

    while(true)
    {
        en0.MoveNext(); yield return en0.Current;
        en1.MoveNext(); yield return en1.Current;
        en2.MoveNext(); yield return en2.Current;
        en3.MoveNext(); yield return en3.Current;
        en4.MoveNext(); yield return en4.Current;
    }
}
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2249415/268581), Eric Lippert recommends against using enumerators.

Is there a good way to express the above without explicit enumerators?

---

What is the above generator used for?

In *A Book of Abstract Algebra* by Charles C. Pinter, exercise 5.F.3 states:

Let *G* be the group `{e, a, b, b^2, b^3, ab ab^2, ab^3}` whose generators satisfy `a^4 = e`, `a^2 = b^2`, `ba = ab^3`. Write the table of *G*. (*G* is called the *quaternion group*.)

The following program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace pinter_5.F._1
{
    class Program
    {
        static IEnumerable<string> generate(string s)
        {
            yield return new Regex("e").Replace(s, "", 1);

            yield return new Regex("aaaa").Replace(s, "e", 1);
            yield return new Regex("aa").Replace(s, "bb", 1);
            yield return new Regex("ba").Replace(s, "abbb", 1);

            yield return new Regex("bb").Replace(s, "aa", 1);

            var en0 = generate(new Regex("e").Replace(s, "", 1)).GetEnumerator();
            var en1 = generate(new Regex("aaaa").Replace(s, "e", 1)).GetEnumerator();
            var en2 = generate(new Regex("aa").Replace(s, "bb", 1)).GetEnumerator();
            var en3 = generate(new Regex("ba").Replace(s, "abbb", 1)).GetEnumerator();
            var en4 = generate(new Regex("bb").Replace(s, "aa", 1)).GetEnumerator();

            while(true)
            {
                en0.MoveNext(); yield return en0.Current;
                en1.MoveNext(); yield return en1.Current;
                en2.MoveNext(); yield return en2.Current;
                en3.MoveNext(); yield return en3.Current;
                en4.MoveNext(); yield return en4.Current;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var G = new List<string>() { "e", "a", "b", "bb", "bbb", "ab", "abb", "abbb" };

            foreach (var x in G)
            {
                foreach (var y in G)
                {
                    var result = generate(x + y).First(elt => G.Contains(elt));

                    Console.Write($"{x,-5} {y,-5} = {result,-5} |");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

displays the table:

[image]

Comment: You can use `Zip`, since you're assuming `en*` sequences are of the same length

Comment: Hey @Rob. I get that you can zip two IEnumerables as such: `generate(...).Zip(generate(...), selector`. But its not clear what to specify as the `selector`.

Comment: The selector creates a new object for each pair in the sequences, so you might have something like `a.Zip(b, (left, right) => new { a = left, b = right })` which transforms `[1,2,3]` `[4,5,6]` into `[{a = 1, b = 4}, {a = 2, b = 5}, {a = 3, b = 6}]`

Comment: @Rob Right. But note that I'm consuming the items in the manually "zipped" sequences above one at a time. `Zip` forces you to combine them. (I know about `Zip` and had considered it, but it wasn't clear that it can be used here easily.)

Comment: Yep - that would be fine. In the above example, you'd loop through the zip for example: `foreach(var pair in zip) { yield return pair.a; yield return pair.b; }`

Comment: @Rob OK, I've posted an answer in terms of `Zip`. It is fewer lines, but having to pack and unpack the pairs is a little noisy.

Comment: @Rob Posted another example in terms of Eric's `ZipMany`. Looks pretty good. Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: To clarify: sometimes using enumerators is unavoidable; sometimes you really do need fine-grained control over how the sequence is enumerated. But my *preference* would be to *build a higher-level sequence operation* -- like `ZipMany` - that uses enumerators, and then apply the higher-level operation to your problem.  Try to keep mechanism code and business code separated.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments above, Rob mentions that one approach is to use `Zip`.

Here's a version of `generate` using `Zip`:

```
static IEnumerable<string> generate(string s)
{
    yield return new Regex("e").Replace(s, "", 1);

    yield return new Regex("aaaa").Replace(s, "e", 1);
    yield return new Regex("aa").Replace(s, "bb", 1);
    yield return new Regex("ba").Replace(s, "abbb", 1);

    yield return new Regex("bb").Replace(s, "aa", 1);

    var seq =
        generate(new Regex("e").Replace(s, "", 1))
            .Zip(generate(new Regex("aaaa").Replace(s, "e", 1)), (a, b) => new { a = a, b = b }).SelectMany(elt => new[] { elt.a, elt.b })
            .Zip(generate(new Regex("aa").Replace(s, "bb", 1)), (a, b) => new { a = a, b = b }).SelectMany(elt => new[] { elt.a, elt.b })
            .Zip(generate(new Regex("ba").Replace(s, "abbb", 1)), (a, b) => new { a = a, b = b }).SelectMany(elt => new[] { elt.a, elt.b })
            .Zip(generate(new Regex("bb").Replace(s, "aa", 1)), (a, b) => new { a = a, b = b }).SelectMany(elt => new[] { elt.a, elt.b });

    foreach (var elt in seq) yield return elt;
}
```

Comment: The `SelectMany()` is going to flatten them in an incorrect order for `>2` sequences. Instead of `[a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2]`, it will generate `[a1, c1, b1, c2]`. Also, zip will end once either sequence finishes. Here, c will finish first (since it's emitting twice as fast) and you'll be missing items from `a` and `b`. This effect gets worse with more sequences.

Comment: @Rob For this particular application, the order of the elements doesn't matter. Also, each subsequence is infinite, so none are expected to finish before another.

Answer (score 0):

Eric Lippert includes a `ZipMany` function in the post referenced above. Here's a version of `generate` using `ZipMany`:

```
static IEnumerable<string> generate(string s)
{
    yield return new Regex("e").Replace(s, "", 1);

    yield return new Regex("aaaa").Replace(s, "e", 1);
    yield return new Regex("aa").Replace(s, "bb", 1);
    yield return new Regex("ba").Replace(s, "abbb", 1);

    yield return new Regex("bb").Replace(s, "aa", 1);

    var seq =
        ZipMany(new[]
            {
                generate(new Regex("e").Replace(s, "", 1)),
                generate(new Regex("aaaa").Replace(s, "e", 1)),
                generate(new Regex("aa").Replace(s, "bb", 1)),
                generate(new Regex("ba").Replace(s, "abbb", 1)),
                generate(new Regex("bb").Replace(s, "aa", 1))
            },
            elts => elts).SelectMany(items => items);

    foreach (var elt in seq) yield return elt;
}
```