# WordprocessingDocument: How can I replace a specific text enclosed in a set of special characters?

Tags: c#, regex, ms-word, openxml, wordprocessingml

I need to generate several word documents based on a template.
In each document a need to replace certain strings (all enclosed in a double set of curly braces,just to tell them apart easily).

I tried :

** Reading the whole template and replace all the occurrences of a word    using Regex.Replace

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
    {
        string docText = null;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
            docText = sr.ReadToEnd();

        foreach (var key in keysToSearch)
            docText = new Regex(key, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Replace(docText, replaceText);

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
            sw.Write(docText);
    }
```

** And also getting access to every Text element

```
using ( WordprocessingDocument doc =
                    WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"yourpath\testdocument.docx", true))
            {
                var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                var paras = body.Elements<Paragraph>();

                foreach (var para in paras)
                {
                    foreach (var run in para.Elements<Run>())
                    {
                        foreach (var text in run.Elements<Text>())
                        {
                            if (text.Text.Contains("{{FullName}}"))
                            {
                                text.Text = text.Text.Replace("{{FullName}}", "replaced-text");
                            }
                        }
                     }
                }
          }
```

But none of the above solutions worked, because in .docx files all those curly brackets are store in different text elements ( `<w:t>` ) :

```
            <w:r w:rsidR="00786C31" w:rsidRPr="00475C3D">
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:b/>
                    <w:sz w:val="36"/>
                    <w:highlight w:val="yellow"/>
                    <w:lang w:val="es-PE"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>{{</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
            <w:r w:rsidR="001B7FC4" w:rsidRPr="00475C3D">
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:b/>
                    <w:sz w:val="36"/>
                    <w:highlight w:val="yellow"/>
                    <w:lang w:val="es-PE"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>FullName</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
            <w:r w:rsidR="00786C31" w:rsidRPr="00475C3D">
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:b/>
                    <w:sz w:val="36"/>
                    <w:highlight w:val="yellow"/>
                    <w:lang w:val="es-PE"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>}}</w:t>
            </w:r>
```

Is there any way I can use special characters to mark a variable in my templates so that I can then easily find and replace them?

Comment: Just to summarize (no I don't have an answer): You have a document like "Mr. {{LastName}}'s first name is {{FirstName}}", and that get's stored as (roughly) Run ("Mr. ") + Run("{{") + SpellStart() + Run("LastName") + SpellEnd() + Run("}}") + etc.  Is that about rignt?  You may find that changing your inner-most `foreach` to be a more general loop that checks for the "{{", then looks at the next element (for the key) and then the one after that looking for "}}".  If you get a match, look the key up in a dictionary and so the replacement (throwing out the {{ and }} runs).

Comment: Remember that you can fake out a `foreach` by getting the enumerator and calling `MoveNext` and `Current` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248985/using-ienumerable-without-foreach-loop)

Comment: Is there any way of forcing ANY special character to remain in the same position it was originally written?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea.  My experience with OpenXML is writing (word processing and spreadsheet) docs, not trying to read them.  I usually hack away at it until it works (often using the OpenXML Productivity Tool).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenXML tag search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697701/openxml-tag-search)

Answer (score 1):

We use similar ways to store a variable to a document and replace it afterwards. 
Some experience about this: If you change a document and simply save it, then this chars are often converted as described above.
I f you choose save as, then the document is more often totally rewritten and the special char´s will remain. We have good experience with double chars like ||lastname|| to have them saved correct when using the save as method.  The pipe sign looks not to be encoded by MS word

Comment: Thank you, but I tried with the pipe and other characters and still no luck. I even tried saving the doc as you suggested and unfortunately it didn't work either.